# Checkbox input, styled as a button is no longer triggering the 'change' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to implement a checkbox as a button as described here:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

I am trying to listen to the the change event of the underlying checkbox so I can do foo(), however the event is not firing, see my jsFiddle here:

**[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/z70oyrwj/)**

Here's my code:

```
 <div class=''> 
   <div class="hideComplete btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" >
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="hideCompleteLabel">Hide completed
        <input type="checkbox" id="hidecomplete"/>
         </label>
   </div>
 </div>
<script>
    $('#hidecomplete').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("I'm checked")
        } else {
           alert("I'm not checked")
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you add jQuery to the fiddle then it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/fzyhos2v/

Comment: Have you checked the console errors? And also are you sure that jQuery library loaded in the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z70oyrwj/1/)**.

You aren't including the jQuery library in your fiddle so just add it make the fiddle works fine with the same code :

```
$('#hidecomplete').on('change', function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert("I'm checked")
  } else {
    alert("I'm not checked")
  }
});
```

**NOTE :** Please check the console for the errors, so you could notice :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Hope this helps.